# CosmosDB + NestJS: Entity with the specified id already exists in the system

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, nestjs

I have connected my NestJS project with a CosmosDB database using the @nestjs/azure-database package. I have successfully created a first item in my database, but whenever I try to add another one (create function), it gives me following error:

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Entity with the specified id already exists in the system., 
RequestStartTime: 2020-10-22T11:54:32.5660620Z, RequestEndTime: 2020-10-22T11:54:32.5860730Z,  Number of regions attempted:1
ResponseTime: 2020-10-22T11:54:32.5860730Z, StoreResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://cdb-ms-prod-westeurope1-fd37.documents.azure.com:14162/apps/6cfd606f-f95e-4068-9026-f2f1ea7a7521/services/9ef1da94-92b6-488d-afa0-7566d7382073/partitions/4336f3e2-783d-4132-a682-84d5afed64a1/replicas/132474264435072969p/, LSN: 32, GlobalCommittedLsn: 32, PartitionKeyRangeId: 0, IsValid: True, StatusCode: 409, SubStatusCode: 0, RequestCharge: 1.24, ItemLSN: -1, SessionToken: -1#32, UsingLocalLSN: False, TransportException: null, ResourceType: Document, OperationType: Create
```

My entity class is defined as such:

```
import { CosmosDateTime, CosmosPartitionKey, CosmosUniqueKey } from '@nestjs/azure-database';

@CosmosPartitionKey('id')
export class TeamsSupport {
    constructor(botId: string, sessionId: string, version: string, supportId: string, teamsConversationRef: string) {
        this.botId = botId;
        this.version = version;
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.supportId = supportId;
        this.teamsConversationRef = teamsConversationRef;
    }

    id?: string;
    botId: string;
    teamsConversationRef: string;
    version: string;
    supportId: string;
    @CosmosUniqueKey() sessionId: string;
    @CosmosDateTime() createdAt: Date;
    @CosmosDateTime() updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Saving the user credentials, as you can see, the supportId and teamsConversationRef are undefined in first instance:

```
public async saveUserCredentials(sessionId: any, botId: string, version: string) {
        const teamsSupport: TeamsSupport = new TeamsSupport(botId, sessionId, version, undefined, undefined);
        await this.teamsSupportService.create(teamsSupport);
    }
```

The repository class (only the create method):

```
import { Container } from '@azure/cosmos';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/azure-database';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HandoverLogger } from '../logger/handoverlogger.service';
import { TeamsSupport } from './teamssupport.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TeamsSupportRepository {

  constructor(@InjectModel(TeamsSupport) private readonly container: Container, private handoverLogger: HandoverLogger) {
      this.handoverLogger.setContext('ContactRepository');
  }

  async create(item: TeamsSupport): Promise<TeamsSupport> {
    item.createdAt = new Date();
    const response = await this.container.items.create(item);
    this.handoverLogger.verbose(`Create RUs: ${response.requestCharge}`);
    return response.resource;
  }
```

Some things to note:

- The sessionId is always unique in my testing, so that can't be the issue.
- Updating the one item I did already create works without issue with the upsert function
- I have tried deleting the 'id?' parameter in the Entity to no avail

What I'm thinking causes the issue is the id generated by CosmosDB, but I don't really know. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance!

The first item I was able to create (all identification was cut short with ***):

```
{
    "sessionId": "testId",
    "createdAt": "2020-10-22T10:01:40.852Z",
    "id": "368c7693-f57f-4dba-84b2-cd3c0504f088",
    "_rid": "i+NVANCshdgBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/i+NVAA==/colls/i+NVANCshdg=/docs/i+NVANCshdgBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"0800f5fc-0000-0d00-0000-5f915cdd0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "teamsConversationRef": "{\"activityId\":\"1603362010475\",\"user\":{\"id\":\"29:12zv1Zc3R***\",\"name\":\"Ros***\",\"aadObjectId\":\"33070d33-866***\",\"email\":\"jasp***\",\"userPrincipalName\":\"jaspe***\",\"tenantId\":\"8c292c0d-05c***\",\"userRole\":\"user\"},\"bot\":{\"id\":\"28:6ce0c0e***\",\"name\":\"Human Handover\"},\"conversation\":{\"isGroup\":true,\"conversationType\":\"channel\",\"tenantId\":\"8c292***\",\"id\":\"19:02bd604cd4284d4***;messageid=1603360903103\"},\"channelId\":\"msteams\",\"locale\":\"en-GB\",\"serviceUrl\":\"https://smba.trafficman***\"}",
    "supportId": "29:12zv1Zc3RHpHBDKDf3***",
    "updatedAt": "2020-10-22T10:20:13.681Z",
    "_ts": 1603362013
}
```

Comment: Are you actually passing a value for id there? This is required for every item you insert.

Comment: I didn’t at this point, but the id got inserted anyway by cosmosdb, I suppose as a differentiator. Now, I added id to the constructor and use uuid.v4() to generate an id, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the container in Cosmos DB and then restarting my program, thereby creating a new container with the correct PartitionKey. Updating an existing one apparently does not work.

Comment: That's correct, partition key is immutable because it is used in how/where data is physically stored.